# javascript button does not fire the click event automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

i am playing around with some new javascript functions to try to automatically click the button on a web page.

However, the click event of the button does not fire automatically. I have googled some code and it appears to be correct.

I am using IE browser 10

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function haha1()
{
    alert('haha1');
}
</script>

<script>
    document.getElementById('haha').click();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" id = "haha" onClick = "haha1()" value = "lol"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it after the page loads. Basically your script executes before `haha` gets created so it doesn't show your alert.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function haha1()
{
    alert('haha1');
}

function fire_haha() {
    document.getElementById('haha').click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="fire_haha()">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the DOM fully loaded before triggering the event and dccording to unobstrusive javascript. You should not embed javascript into html.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function haha1()
{
    alert('haha1');
}
</script>

<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('haha').onclick = function(){
       haha1();
    };
   document.getElementById('haha').click();
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" id = "haha"  value = "lol"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with jQuery

```
 function fire_haha() { 
          $('#haha').trigger('click'); 
}
```